# Adding 'sort by' drop down on custom page using woocommerce short code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I have created a custom page using woocommerce short code for product categories. At the moment, it's pretty sparse as I've only just started on the new site.

I just need the default 'sort by' drop down element adding but have no idea how to do it.

I found some code here >>[Woocommerce, sort dropdown on shortcode based product lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073317/woocommerce-sort-dropdown-on-shortcode-based-product-lists/33088344?noredirect=1#comment53992987_33088344)

and it certainly placed the drop down I need on the site (although I'd like it aligned left).

The only problem now, is that it's displaying the products with enormous images and all in a single vertical column.

I'm not a PHP programmer and am wondering if I've deleted some important code in the php file I modified. (thank god I took a copy of the original!).

Can anyone help? Is there a better way to add the sort by drop down onto my custom pages?

This is one of the pages I've created >> http://www.sdmtest1.co.uk/notebooks-journals/

Here is the code I added.

```
/**
 * List products in a category shortcode
 *
 * @param array $atts
 * @return string
 */
public static function product_category( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'per_page' => '12',
        'columns'  => '4',
        'orderby'  => 'title',
        'order'    => 'desc',
        'category' => '',  // Slugs
        'operator' => 'IN' // Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
    ), $atts );

    if ( ! $atts['category'] ) {
        return '';
    }

    // Default ordering args
    $ordering_args = WC()->query->get_catalog_ordering_args( $atts['orderby'],    
$atts['order'] );
$orderby = 'title';
$order = 'asc';
if ( isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ) {
    $getorderby = $_GET['orderby'];
}
if ($getorderby == 'popularity') {
    $orderby = 'meta_value_num';
    $order = 'desc';
    $meta_key = 'total_sales';
} elseif ($getorderby == 'rating') {

    $fields .= ", AVG( $wpdb->commentmeta.meta_value ) as average_rating ";

    $where .= " AND ( $wpdb->commentmeta.meta_key = 'rating' OR $wpdb->commentmeta.meta_key IS null ) ";

    $join .= "
        LEFT OUTER JOIN $wpdb->comments ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID)
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->commentmeta ON($wpdb->comments.comment_ID = $wpdb->commentmeta.comment_id)
    ";

    $orderby = "average_rating DESC, $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC";

    $groupby = "$wpdb->posts.ID";   

} elseif ($getorderby == 'date') {
    $orderby = 'date';
    $order = 'desc';
} elseif ($getorderby == 'price') {
    $orderby = 'meta_value_num';
    $order = 'asc';
    $meta_key = '_price';
} elseif ($getorderby == 'price-desc') {
    $orderby = 'meta_value_num';
    $order = 'desc';
    $meta_key = '_price';
}
$args = array(
    'post_type'             => 'product',
    'post_status'           => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
    'orderby'               => $orderby, // $ordering_args['orderby'],
    'order'                 => $order, // $ordering_args['order'],
    'meta_key'              => $meta_key,
    'fields'                => $fields,
    'where'                 => $where,
    'join'                  => $join,
    'groupby'               => $groupby,
    'posts_per_page'        => $per_page,
    'meta_query'            => array(
        array(
            'key'           => '_visibility',
            'value'         => array('catalog', 'visible'),
            'compare'       => 'IN'
        )
    ),
    'tax_query'             => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
            'terms'         => array( esc_attr( $category ) ),
            'field'         => 'slug',
            'operator'      => $operator
        )
    )
);

if ( isset( $ordering_args['meta_key'] ) ) {
    $args['meta_key'] = $ordering_args['meta_key'];
}

ob_start();

$products = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', $args, $atts ) );

$woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $columns;

if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

<div style="width:100%;">
    <div style="float:right">
        <form class="woocommerce-ordering" method="get">
            <select name="orderby" class="orderby">
                <?php
                    $catalog_orderby = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', array(
                        'menu_order' => __( 'Default sorting', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'popularity' => __( 'Sort by popularity', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'rating'     => __( 'Sort by average rating', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'date'       => __( 'Sort by newness', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'price'      => __( 'Sort by price: low to high', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'price-desc' => __( 'Sort by price: high to low', 'woocommerce' )
                    ) );

                    if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_review_rating' ) === 'no' )
                        unset( $catalog_orderby['rating'] );

                    foreach ( $catalog_orderby as $id => $name )
                        echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '" ' . selected( $getorderby, $id, false ) . '>' . esc_attr( $name ) . '</option>';
                ?>
            </select>
            <?php
                // Keep query string vars intact
                foreach ( $_GET as $key => $val ) {
                    if ( 'orderby' === $key || 'submit' === $key )
                        continue;

                    if ( is_array( $val ) ) {
                        foreach( $val as $innerVal ) {
                            echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '[]" value="' . esc_attr( $innerVal ) . '" />';
                        }

                    } else {
                        echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $val ) . '" />';
                    }
                }
            ?>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

        <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

            <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

<?php endif;

woocommerce_reset_loop();
wp_reset_postdata();

return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $columns . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
```

}

I edited in dreamweaver and it flagged a syntax error. I wasn't sure where the code I pasted was to begin and end and I kinda lost this bit in the process.

```
        // Remove ordering query arguments
    WC()->query->remove_ordering_args();

    return $return;
}
```

Thanks,
Loren

Comment: Show us some code, we can tell you if there is something wrong in your code if we don't see it

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073317/woocommerce-sort-dropdown-on-shortcode-based-product-lists/72784024#72784024

Answer (score 0):

If you add the `paginate="true"` attribute to your `[products]` shortcode, then the shortcode, then the `Sort by` dropdown menu will appear on the page.

> I have created a custom page using woocommerce short code for product categories.

You say you're using shortcodes, but you don't provide an example. So I'll make one up.

If you were using this to display all of the products in the "boots" category:

```
[product_category category="boots"]
```

Then change it to this:

```
[product_category category="boots" paginate="true"]
```